# how to create a select without an option by default

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to create a select without a option by default, I have the next list of languages, when I select one and then press the button" addLand", I use .append of jquery to add 1 language to the list, but by default it create an option empty when the page is executed:

```
<select id="langList">
<option></option>
</select>
```

This is my code, what can I change to add a new options elemets without that option empty?

```
 <select id="updLanguage">
            <option value="tr">Turkish‬</option> 
            <option value="uk">Ukrainian‬</option> 
            <option value="ur">Urdu‬</option> 
            <option value="vi">Vietnamese‬</option> 
            <option value="zu">Zulu‬</option>
 </select>
 <input type="button" id="addLang" value="addLang">

<select id="langList">
   <!--when I press the button "addLang" it add a new lang but with an <option></empty> empty before and then the lang add-->
```

".$languages."";?> // its to reload the languages already saved in my DB

script to add new lang to the list

```
$("#addLang").on("click", function(){
   var lang =$("#updLanguage :selected").text();
   var idLang =$("#updLanguage").val();
   $("#langList").append("<option id='"+idLang+"'>"+lang+"</option>");       
});
```

Comment: Works fine on Chrome it doesn't create an empty option http://jsfiddle.net/bW7k7/ What browser are you using?

Comment: @Anton I'm using Chrome too, it works well here, but in my project no, and it's the same code.

Comment: Its working fine..Do you want to check if an option exist dont add something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

http://jsfiddle.net/bW7k7/1/

```
$("#addLang").on("click", function(){
    var lang =$("#updLanguage :selected").text();
    var idLang =$("#updLanguage").val();
    if($("#langList").is("div")) {
        $("#langList").replaceWith($('<select id="langList">' + this.innerHTML + '</select>'));
    }
    $("#langList").append("<option id='"+idLang+"'>"+lang+"</option>");  

});
```

Comment: I can't do that because inside '<select id="langList"></select>' I have a php code <?echo "<option>".$languages."</option>";?> to reload the languages saved in my DB

Comment: Fixed, now it takes the content of _<div id="langList" />_ and places it in the new _select_ element, hope is what u was asking.